# submit form into email admin using php

Tags: php

hye, I'm still new in developing the system. so now, I face the problems in setting my email. Where, after users fill up the form they will submit into admin's email.

Please show me what I suppose to add or edit from this code:

1. formpekerja.php

   ```html
       <?php
       include('db.php');
       ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <!--
       Template Name: Cortex
       Author: <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/">OS Templates</a>
       Author URI: http://www.os-templates.com/
       Licence: Free to use under our free template licence terms
       Licence URI: http://www.os-templates.com/template-terms
       -->
       <html>

        <head>
         <title>e-booking| Borang Pekerja</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        </head>

         <body id="top">
       <!-- ################################################################################################ --> 
       <!-- ################################################################################################ --> 
       <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
       <div class="wrapper row1">
         <header id="header" class="clear"> 
           <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
          
          <div id="logo" class="fl_left">
             <h1><a href="viewbooking.php">Borang Tempahan Bilik</a></h1>
              </div>

           <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
          
           <!-- ################################################################################################ --> 
         </header>
       </div>
       <!-- ################################################################################################ --> 
       <!-- ################################################################################################ --> 
       <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
       <div class="wrapper bgded" style="background-image:url('images/43.jpg');">


       <!-- CSS -->
       <style>

       .formPekerja {
        margin:auto;
       font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
       font-size: 0.8em;
       width: 60em;
       padding: 1em;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       }

       .formPekerja * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       .formPekerja fieldset {
       border: none;
       padding: 0;
       }

       .formPekerja legend,
       .formPekerja label {
       padding: 0;
       font-weight: bold;
       }

       .formPekerja label.choice {
       font-size: 0.9em;
       font-weight: normal;
       }

       .formPekerja input[type="text"],
       .formPekerja input[type="tel"],
       .formPekerja input[type="email"],
       .formPekerja input[type="datetime-local"],
       .formPekerja select,
       .formPekerja textarea {
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
       font-size: 0.9em;
       padding: 0.3em;
       }

       .formPekerja textarea {
       height: 100px;
       }

       .formPekerja button {
       padding: 1em;
       border-radius: 0.5em;
       background: #eee;
       border: none;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-top: 1em;
       }

       .formPekerja button:hover {
       background: #ccc;
       cursor: pointer;
       }
       </style>
       </head>

       <form  class="formPekerja" method="POST" id="ebooking" action="hantar.php">

       form details..

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="hantar" onClick="return validateForm();"> 
         </form>
   ```
2. hantar.php

```html
<?php
  require('db.php');
  include('test2.php');

  if ( $_POST['hantar'] );

  $staffName=$_POST['staffName'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $company=$_POST['company'];
  $types=$_POST['types'];
  $location=$_POST['location'];
  $startDate=$_POST['startDate'];
  $endDate=$_POST['endDate'];
  $requestDate=$_POST['requestDate'];
  $startTime=$_POST['startTime'];
  $endTime=$_POST['endTime'];
  $baverage=$_POST['baverage'];
  $purpose=$_POST['purpose'];
  $capacity=$_POST['capacity'];
  mysql_query("Insert into booking(staffName,email,capacity,company, types,location,startDate,endDate,startTime,endTime,requestDate,purpose,baverage)
   values ('$staffName','$email','$capacity','$company','$types','$location','$startDate','$endDate','$startTime','$endTime','$requestDate','$purpose','$baverage')");
  
  header("location:viewbooking.php");
?>
```

3. test2.php

```html
<?php
  require('db.php');
  include 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mailto = $_POST ['mail_to'];
  $mailSub = $_POST['mail_sub'];
  $mailMsg = $_POST['mail_msg'];
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail-> smtpServer = ''; //ip accepted as well
  $mail-> port = ""; // should be 25 by default
  $mail-> timeout = ""; //typical timeout. try 45 for slow servers
  $mail-> username = ''; //the login for your smtp
  $mail-> password = ''; //the pass for your smtp
  $mail-> localhost = ""; //this seems to work always
  $mail-> newLine = ""; //var just for nelines
  $mail-> SetFrom;
  $mail-> Subject = $mailSub;
  $mail-> Body = $mailMsg;
  $mail-> AddAddress($mailto);

  if(!$mail->send())
  {
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Mail Sent";
  }

?>
```

Comment: what's your problem with the code

Comment: error found on this line.. if(!$mail->send());
{

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: i dont know, local host just mention like this "Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\blabla\test2.php on line 23"

Comment: remove semicolon at the end of if condition if(!$mail->send());

Comment: could i show the full codes from the form?

Comment: Can you show the form code

Comment: if(!$mail->send());  remove semicolon.

Comment: yeahh, its work. thank you but where i suppose to add coding for email admin. i mean, to make sure the form submit into email admin.

Comment: this line $mail-> AddAddress($mailto);  $mailto is your admin mail  addaddress mean to mail address

Comment: i already show the codes @ZacWebb